# Setting styles for desktop only (responsive site)

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

OK, I hope this all makes sense, but here we go...

I'm currently building a responsive site, however the desktop version has already been done. And I have a image within a div wrapper. Which has an on hover state and displays some test. This is all done through CSS.

Now on the tablet I want to be able to create a dropdown for the text rather than a hover state. But the problem is when I hover over the div that I need to click on the tablet version (max-width: 1024px) the content shows. But i only want it to show onClick from the jquery.

Here is the CSS site which is set on the site itself:

```
.textHoverWrapOne:hover div.block-50_textHoverOne, .textHoverWrapTwo:hover div.block-50_textHoverTwo, .textHoverWrapThree:hover div.block-50_textHoverThree,.textHoverWrapFour:hover div.block-50_textHoverFour, .textHoverWrapFive:hover div.block-50_textHoverFive, .textHoverWrapSix:hover div.block-50_textHoverSix{
    visibility: visible;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

I want to be able to remove the styles for the tablet and anything smaller. But I can't seem to clear them. The only way I can think to do it is by removing the class with jQuery on mobile/tablet devices, but it seems far too hacky.

Is there a way I can set the styles to only appear on anything over 1024px using media queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  // your rules here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! No idea why i didn't think of that! But thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Very easily:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
```